# For gcc, is link time optimization (-flto) as optimized as whole program optimization (-fwhole-program)?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm looking to create a highly optimized program running under linux and was wondering if multiple C files should be individually compiled or instead combined into a single monolithic C file, then compiled? For example,

Here's a *single* compilation unit

> gcc -o single -fwhole-program -O2 helloworld.c

**helloworld.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(const char * name)
{
  printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}

int main(void)
{
  hello("world");
  return 0;
}
```

Here's a *multiple* compilation unit

> ```
>  gcc -o multiple -flto -O2 hello.c world.c
> ```

**hello.h**

```
void hello(const char * name);
```

**hello.c**

```
#include "hello.h"

int main(void)
{
  hello("world");
  return 0;
}
```

**world.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void hello(const char * name)
{
  printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

Using these disassembly commands

> objdump -S --disassemble single > single.asm

> objdump -S --disassemble multiple > multiple.asm

both single.asm and multiple.asm outputs were identical:

[image: compare]

**Question**

Is it true to assume that using the optimized options **-flto** and **-fwhole-program** will produce the same optimized binaries?

Comment: `-fwhole-program` isn't an optimization option; it changes the behaviour of the code (makes the implementation non-conforming). See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gccint/WHOPR.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is link time optimization (-flto) as optimized as whole program optimization (-fwhole-program)?

No. These are different options with different meaning.

> a highly optimized

Use LTO, then PGO.

> if multiple C files should be individually compiled or instead combined into a single monolithic C file, then compiled?

LTO exists exactly just for that, so that compiling multiple C files individually is the same as one C file.

> Is it true to assume that using the optimized options -flto and -fwhole-program will produce the same optimized binaries?

No.